# replacing item in list while iterating

Tags: python, python-2.7

*From Google's Python Class*

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
# Copyright 2010 Google Inc.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

# Google's Python Class
# http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/

# Additional basic list exercises

# D. Given a list of numbers, return a list where
# all adjacent == elements have been reduced to a single element,
# so [1, 2, 2, 3] returns [1, 2, 3]. You may create a new list or
# modify the passed in list.
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  x = 0
  newlist = []
  for x in range(0,len(nums),1):
    if nums[x] == nums[x+1]:
      newlist.append(nums[x])
      x = x+2
    else:
      newlist.append(nums[x])
      x = x+1

  return nums
```

it is giving me an error saying that the list index is out of range but I am not sure what is wrong. I read somewhere that you cannot replace values in a list while iterating using a for loop but have no idea how to fix that. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its probably due to `nums[x+1]` being out of range. `x` only goes from `0` to `len(nums) - 1` meaning that when `x` is `len(nums)-1`, you will essentially be indexing into `nums[len(nums)]` which will be one past the end of `nums` (remember the last index in a non-empty list is `1` less than its length, since we start counting indexes from `0`).

Comment: +1, this minimally answers _this_ question. There are some other bugs, but they should probably be a new question

Answer (score 2):

The index `x+1` will be out of range when x is the index of the very last element. In addition, you are creating a new list yet you return the old one.

Modifying the value of `x` isn't doing what you think as it is being *reset* at every loop iteration.

Here is an alternative implementation:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  newlist = []
  for i in range(0, len(nums)):
    if i == len(nums) - 1:      # Avoid out of range error.
      newlist.append(nums[i])
    elif nums[i] == nums[i+1]:  # Skip until the last repeat
      continue
    else:  
      newlist.append(nums[i])
  return newlist
```

Comment: no worries, I thought the same thing when I first saw the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this using zip and list comprehension:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
    return [n[0] for n in zip(nums, nums[1:]) if n[0] != n[1]]
```

Comment: You should just use `!=` for not equal, since `<>` has been removed from Python3

Answer (score 2):

The index`x+1`goes out of range on the last element of the list, whose index is`len(nums)-1`-- there is no`nums[len(nums)]`.

It would be really simple to just use the[`groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby)function in the[`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby)module:

```
from itertools import groupby

def remove_adjacent(nums):
    return [k for k, _ in groupby(nums)]

print remove_adjacent([1, 2, 2, 2, 3])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: +1, I guess the correct answer for `[1, 2, 2, 2, 3]` isn't `[1, 2, 2, 3]`

Comment: @gnibbler: That's how I interpret "all adjacent == elements have been reduced to a single element".